# Swift if-else. The else block is never executed when condition == false

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to perform a specific segue based on one of the fields of the request's response. When "**accountRes.complete ==true**" the code executes correctly but when it equals false the else block is never executed.

```
AF.request(Endpoints.account, method: .get, headers: headers).response { response in debugPrint (response)
    guard let data = response.data,
        let accountRes = try? JSONDecoder().decode(AccountResponse.self, from: data) else {
        return
    }
    
    debugPrint (accountRes)
    if accountRes.complete == true {
        self.performSegue (withIdentifier: "home_segue", sender: nil)
    } else {
        print ("Not complete")
        /// Code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `if` expression is reached and `accountRes.complete` is not `true` then the `else` scope will definitely be executed. By the way `== true` is redundant if `accountRes.complete` is non-optional.

It's not being executed if a `DecodingError` occurs. Add a `do catch` block, remove the question mark from `try?` and print the `error` instance in the `catch` scope.

Comment: Thank you! It was indeed a problem with decoding. I updated my model and it worked. 
Also thanks for the redundancy tip.